# Install Java on MAC OSX 10.8.2 Error calling: CFMessagePortCreateRemote

Tags: java, macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

Hello I am trying to install Java on my mac with osx 10.8.2.

If I am typing `java -version` in the terminal, I get the following error:

`No Java runtime present, requesting install.
2013-03-08 08:36:03.477 java[1192:707] JLRequestRuntimeInstall: Error calling: CFMessagePortCreateRemote`

Yesterday I completely uninstalled java 6 from my pc with
`sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

After downloading Java 7u17 from the oracle site and installing it, the installer said that Java was completely installed. I typed again `java -version` and it gave me the same error (No Java Runtime present).

Do you know any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by uninstalling everything with java and installing the java packet with the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Install the JDK from [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) - Follow the instructions from: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html)

Once installed run `java -version` again.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this with the help of my IT department. Since Apple doesn't support Java any more we need to figure out a few things. First ensure that you have the latest version of Java down loaded for the Mac. After you do that you will need to follow these steps.

Open your system preferences in the top left corner and go to the Java tab and select view. There you will find the version of the Java and it will already be selected or checked. If so go over to the Security tab and unselect the Enable Java content in the browser and then reselect this item.( The IT person said this does something but I didn't notice anything). Then  Proceed to JavaTester.org in Safari and automatically you will see what Java version you are using.  You may have to refresh multiple times to eventually see your Java Version show in the pink box in the center of the screen.

Hope this helps,

David